# Generate TS files for HLS VOD streaming with ffmpeg dynamically on request

Tags: ffmpeg, streaming

I Have huge archive of diferent (even older formáty like AVI) video footages and no place / time to reencode. I would like to implement web based browsable catalogue and want to let video play via HLS streaming. Have implemented own webserver in .net and wrapped ffmpeg to be able work with video. Thumbnails Jpg generating done successfully. Question is how to call ffmpeg to genetate single TS file from the midle of some very long file when webserver is asked for. I understand that it is easy to pregenerate it before, and let the webserver just serve the existing files, but it is not the way in this case. I would like to pregenerate just m3u8 files planning split for example by 10 sec fragments of some defined quality. And then i would like to let webserver wait for TS file requests and serve them dynamically as it goes. So need is to call ffmpeg generate TS file of specified duration and offset from begining of file. Is it possible? Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: FFmpeg, can of course, generate a file of specified duration and offset. `ffmpeg -ss 4000 -t 10 -i fullfile.mp4 -preset faster -g 50 VoDfile.ts`. If you need to create segments, `ffmpeg -ss 4000 -i fullfile.mp4 -preset faster -g 50 -f segment -segment_time 10 VoDfseg%d.ts`